# In jquery, combine multiple textbox values into one textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the 4 text box values into one text box then i want to count the values.

I tried the following but i want to do perfectly.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("smsmessage") %>
</div>
```

The above one is result textbox.

**In Jquery**

```
var  message = "Msg - will you be interested for a sms in " + $("#SmsLocation").val() + " for " + $("#SmsVacancy").val() + " with " + $("#SmsCompanyName").val() + " contact(" + $("#SmsMobileNo").val() + ") or mailto (" + $("#SmsEmailId").val() + ").(" + $("#SmsContactPerson").val() + ")";
```

I am taking these values from all other text boxes and i want to show into `smsmessage` text box. In this text box i want to count all those values.

**For Counting i have tried**

```
var len = $(this).val().length;
            if (len >= 160) {
                var output = $(this).val().substring(0, 160);
                $(this).val(output);
            } else {
                $('#charNum').html(160 - len);
            }
```

Please help me to combine and work all these things?

Comment: you want to count the number of character?

Comment: you want display message in SmsEmailId ?

Comment: what do you mean with want to do perfectly?

Comment: It means i did 50 percentage. I want to do count the values and show into the new text box.

Comment: still the question is not clear. Can you create a fiddle for that.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt test it but if you add name attribute to you text inputs, you can do it in selector:

```
var combined = $("input[name*='combinedText']").val();
```